# How to convert LESS to CSS automatically without IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, less

I am using .net core to try to map less file to css,but it always remind me 404 error.
my project wasn't use IIS to startup.
I tried to install nuget dotless plugin but I can not find bundles.cs in asp.net core project.

[image]

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

LESS files need to be compiled into CSS as part of the build process. This is possible now in Visual Studio, though it requires some setting up. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa

Comment: your link goes to font awesome website

Comment: Seems like this process is no longer supported. This answer has some updated info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726029/how-to-compile-less-sass-files-in-visual-studio-2017