# How do I solve 'Web Compiler found an error in compilerconfig.json'?

Tags: json

On trying to re-compile all files in a solution, using Visual Studio 2017, I get this uninformative error message:

Web Compiler found an error in compilerconfig.json

To begin with, there is more than one compilerconfig.json file in the solution.

Secondly, there is no indication whatsoever of what the error is, where it occurs (line number, for instance).

Any ideas how I can go about solving this?

Answer (score 42):

In Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, right-click the compilerconfig.json file and click "Task Runner Explorer".  In the left pane you will see "compilerconfig.json/all files", right-click on it and then click on "Run".  You will see the details of the execution which, in my case, included the useful information about how to correct the error.

Comment: I do not see "Task Runner Explorer" as an option when I right-click compilerconfig.json in Solution Explorer.

Comment: I am now able to see this. The only thing I did which I think could have made it appear is restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: When I do this it just says "Process terminated with code 0." but when I run it by right clicking on Web Compiler --> re-compile all files it runs successfully but I can't see the output.

Comment: Normally, when 0 is returned, it means that it worked.  So it looks like you corrected the error or that it was a one time error...

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue for myself by using *individual* file compiling, instead of "All files".

I was getting a "Compiling successful!" message, but that didn't seem true because my compile file didn't contain my change. So here's what I did:

1. Open **Window > Task Runner Explorer**. In your left column, there is a task for "All Files". That's fine. Ignore it.
2. Compile your SCSS files individually. Do this by right clicking on each SCSS file in that list, and then **Bindings > After Build**. (Or add the task to whatever event you prefer. I chose After Build.)
3. Open any SCSS file in your project and add a test. I added something like `#TEST2 {color: hotpink;}` to my SCSS file.
4. Now when you save, your compiling takes a few seconds longer. Now open main.css and see if your change (`#TEST2`) exists in the file.

[image]

Comment: **Task Runner Explorer** can now be found under **View > Other Windows > Task Runner Explorer** in VS2019+

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this and didn't find an easy way but I got past it.

My issue turns out to be a missing input file that was supposed to be compiled.

Method of attack:

1. Try to compile each compilerconfig.json file (right-click -> Web Compiler -> re-compile all files)
2. repeat until you find the file in question
3. Remove all data from this file and add entries in one at a time (or scan it to make sure your files are there, which ever fits your situation)

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that the Web Compiler didn't install successfully.  I had the same problem as described in the other answers and went down a rabbit hole to figure out why I couldn't compile.  Turns out I had to help the tool install itself.  See this comment for details:

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/390#issuecomment-475427735

Once I did the steps listed in that comment, I able to both compile files again and was explicitly told by the tool which line of my SCSS had an error.

Answer (score 0):

**For an information:**

I got the same error in VS2019 webcompiler. And I found a solution ie;

Project should be open as a **"Web Site"**.

Do not open as a folder. This simple thing is solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following Yepeekai's advice about Task Runner Explorer led me to solve my problem (I wanted to see where I'd made a syntax error in my SCSS).

[image]

As this shows, if you expand the SCSS node you can see the file which has caused the syntax error (and what it was).

Is this really the easiest way to do this though?