# Visual Studio 2017 edition - not adding scss changes to css

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-2017

I have the visual studio professional 2017 edition and when I make changes to a scss file it doesnt update the changes in real-time, but the scss changes dont get inserted into the css file that goes with it, previously I used mindscape but it doesnt appear to be supported in this version.

Comment: `sass --watch <input>:<output>` <-- What do you have that is supposed to be doing this?

Comment: supposedly visual studio is supposed to take care of this, the setup is literally visual studio and git...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile less/sass files in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726029/how-to-compile-less-sass-files-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: So VS 2017 still needs a scss to css compiler? and Gulp I'm assuming is the 'mindscape' alternative - i'll go and have a look in a sec, I dont want to download something for my entire team however, id like to sand box this to my local solution and see what works.

Comment: Looks that way. Best of luck.

Comment: Just so you know you were absolutely right you do need a compiler, we decided on web compiler in the end, so thank you so very much!